# SL 4: ScrollViewer - RequestBringIntoView

Tags: silverlight-4.0, scrollviewer

How can I find the component in a ScrollViewer that handles the RequestBringIntoView event?
It isn't exposed on the two ScrollBar parts (not directly, anyway).
Thanks for any pointers...

**UPDATE:**  Related:  Can I get the ScrollContentPresenter part of the ScrollViewer?  How?
Thanks --

**Bigger picture:**
We have a large Canvas contained in a ScrollViewer.  At runtime, an arbitrary number of UserControls (I'll call them 'Blobs') are added to the canvas from the db.  Their position and content come from the db.  A user can 'select' a blob by clicking on it, and its appearance changes to indicate it is selected.
If the user uses a scrollbar to move the selected blob out of view, then clicks on another blob, the Canvas is scrolled so the previously-out-of-view blob is in view again.  I assume this is due to some object raising the RequestBringIntoView, and the ScrollViewer is handling it.
Hope this makes sense...

**Yet more info:**
Added a handler (sb_ValueChanged) to the Scrollviewer's scrollbar ValueChanged event.  Here's the stack from the mouse click that precipitates the scrolling:

> OurControl.sb_ValueChanged()  System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase.OnValueChanged()    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBar.OnValueChanged()    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase.OnValuePropertyChanged()
>   System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications()
>   System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue()
>   System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal()
>   System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue()
>   System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.InvalidateScrollInfo()  System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.VerifyScrollData()
>   System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.ArrangeOverride() 
>   System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeOverride()

If only I could find out what the FrameworkElement that starts the mischief actually is...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry... it doesn't seems to exist like it does in WPF. [Check this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotjosh/archive/2009/11/05/bringintoview-extension-method-for-silverlight-with-behavior.aspx) for a handy solution.

**Update**: Ok... for this you might need to walk the visual tree and some sort of recursive search need to be done. However, assuming you are using the default template for the scrollviewer [as seen here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278065%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you can directly ask for the ScrollContentPresenter with something like this:

```
var BorderChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyScrollViewer, 0);
var GridChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(BorderChild, 0);
var ScrollContentPresenterChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(GridChild, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, very interesting.  Unfortunately, the scrollviewer is scrolling unexpectedly, so we want to handle the RequestBringIntoView event to find out what object is triggering it.

Comment: Ohh... you already have some sort of RequestBringIntoView working ?

Comment: We have done nothing explicit about RequestBringIntoView.  See the updated OP for a narrative of the problem we are seeing and trying to solve.  Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Alas, it doesn't look like ScrollContentPresenter will actually help us...  Thanks for the reply and link, I expect it will be useful in the future.  Very frustrating trying to figure out what the heck is causing the Canvas to scroll...